# Имитировать collider2d, в качестве "воображаемого" препятствия для rigidbody2d

Tags: unity3d

Есть группа объектов, каждый из них имеет компоненты СircleСollider2d, Rigidbody2d.
Все они движутся в одном направлении с помощью метода AddForce(), вызываемого в FixedUpdate().

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно сделать так, чтобы когда объекты переместятся к определенному месту в пространстве (ВАЖНО: именно к некоторому месту, не к коллайдеру), они не смогли пройти дальше. Чтобы сила продолжала действовать на них всех, но пройти они не могли.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По сути, мне надо имитировать коллайдер. Почему именно имитировать, а не использовать готовое решение, рассказывать очень долго (если очень кратко - из за производительности и специфики этих "препятствий")

Comment: А на столкновения между собою этой группы объектов все равно?( производительность уже не нужна)

Comment: Я очень сильно упростил описание задачи. В моем случае, препятствие не является прямой линией или какой либо геометрической фигурой. Их количество соответствует количеству объектов, поэтому производительность упадет вдвое.

Comment: Когда задача сводится к оптимизации, надо максимально подробно описывать, ибо это переход к частному решению. Ну можно триггер сделать, если пересекут зафризить смещение у  rigidbody.    Вообще не понятно, для каких целей, пиши подробней

Comment: Простите, не смог удержаться:
 `void Update () {
  if (transform.position.x > gandalf.position.x)
   YouShallNotPass ();
 }
 void YouShallNotPass(){
  transform.position = new Vector2 (gandalf.position.x, transform.position.y);
 }`

Comment: Если перемещать твердые тела с помощью прямого доступа к координатам, физический движок спасибо не скажет. А так да, смешно.